# Finding maximal subset of linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a set of functions in one variable. I wish to find the basis of the corresponding spanning set

Example: $$\left\{1,\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}},\frac{1}{1-x},\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-x}\right\}$$ may reduce to $$\left\{1,\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}},\frac{1}{1-x}\right\}.$$

Sure, I can sample the functions over some set of points $x_i$ and reduce the problem to same problem with vectors, but I have a big set (19 functions) and exact basis computation using `QRDecomposition` takes long and inexact is not very robust.

Comment: Spanning over what base field?

Comment: Over reals. Or i don't understand the question

Comment: I was wondering because it is not obvious to me how to write `sqrt(x)/(1-x)` as a linear combination of the other three.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Here it is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-x} =  \frac{1 + \sqrt{x}}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - x} = 
\frac{1}{1 - \sqrt{x}}- \frac{1}{1 - x} 
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach that might work out. Use `GroebnerBasis` to set up all polynomial relations, then reduce to see where there may be linear dependencies. We use surrogate variables to define algebraic relations for roots and reciprocals, so `sx` stands in for `sqrt(x)` below, and similar for the reciprocal variables `xr1` and `sxr2`. We also use new variables to denote the basis elements, and give their defining polynomials in terms of the prior variables.

```
polys = {sx^2 - x, xr1*(1 - x) - 1, sxr2*(1 - sx) - 1, b1 - 1,
    b2 - sxr2, b3 - xr1, b4 - sx*xr1};
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {sxr2, xr1, sx, x, b1, b2, b3, b4}]

(* Out[3]= {-b3 + b3^2 - b4^2, 
 b2 - b3 - b4, -1 + b1, -1 + b3 - b4^2 + b4^2 x, 
 1 - b3 + b3 x, -b4 + sx + b4 x, -b3 + xr1, -b3 - b4 + sxr2} *)
```

Now we reduce all the basis variables.

```
PolynomialReduce[{b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
  gb, {sxr2, xr1, sx, x, b1, b2, b3, b4}][[All, 2]]

(* Out[4]= {1, b3 + b4, b3, b4} *)
```

So `b2` is written as a linear combination of `b3` and `b4`.

To use this approach in general you might need to have a term ordering that minimizes degree at least for the basis variables. Else you could get nonlinear algebraic relations that might, in a different term ordering, become linear. At least I think that could happen.

Comment: Interesting, but might be very slow for set of ~20 functions. For now I'm just using QR decomposition with 1000 digits on a set of ~100 points. That is pretty quick and seems to work ok.

Comment: Good method. You might instead consider `NullSpace` (use a few more points than functions, maybe 5-10 or so). Can do with exact or approximate arithmetic. Also you can row reduce the result to canonicalize the relations.